# Get the sum of a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

How do I return the sum of this vector array of integers? The code I have below returns the wrong value.

```
int simpleArraySum(vector<int> ar) {
    int sum = 0;
    int length = sizeof(ar);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        sum += ar[i];
    }
    return sum;

}
```

Comment: The `sizeof` operator returns the size of the data structure.  The `std::vector` usually has a pointer to data.  Use `std::vector::size()` method, e.g. `ar.length`.

Answer (score 3):

For starters the vector should be passed to the function by reference. Otherwise a redundant copy of the vector will be created. Moreover the parameter should be declared with constant reference because the vector itself is not changed in the function.

For the sum you should use the type `long long int` because it is not excluded that there can be an overflow.

This declaration

```
int length = sizeof(ar);
```

does not make sense. The variable `length` keeps the size of the object of the type `std::vector<int>` not the number of elements stored in the vector.

So the function can be defined for example the following way

```
long long int simpleArraySum( const std::vector<int> & ar )
{
    long long int sum = 0;

    for ( const auto &item : ar ) sum += item;

    return sum;
}
```

Another approach is to use the standard algorithm `std::accumulate` declared in the header `<numeric>`. For example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

//...

long long int simpleArraySum( const std::vector<int> & ar )
{
    return std::accumulate( std::begin( ar ), std::end( ar ), 0ll );
}
```

Comment: Better yet, use C++20 `std::span` by value.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
int simpleArraySum(vector<int> ar) {
    return std::accumulate(ar.begin(), ar.end(), 0);
}
```

In any case, your `length` initialization is wrong, it should be:

```
int length = ar.size();
```

If you are still having unexpected results, it is likely that you are either under/overflowing `sum` (likely, use a wider type) or that you have too many elements to fit in an `int` (unlikely, switch to `std::size_t` or use a range-for loop instead).

Comment: This is the problem that I am trying to solve: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/simple-array-sum/problem. Instead of getting 31 as the result, I am getting 1203237048. Any ideas why? I can't believe that just 6 elements in an array is causing any overflow issues!!!

Comment: @Welshie321  See Vlad's answer! Your `int length = sizeof(ar);` is just wrong, as Vlad has explained.